# How to set multiline title for UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I split the title string of a UITableViewRowAction in two lines? ...like Apple has done it in their mail app (iPhone); swipe right in the email list and you'll see the action "Mark as Unread", written on two lines.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried placing a newline character in the string? "Line1\nLine2"

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you also know how to change font and font size of such a title?

Comment: Only the title string, background color, style / background effect can be changed for these. Although you could always just add a background view and roll your own code to make this behavior as many others have done in the past before this was released.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never received a response on the comment so I'll assume you tried it and it worked. Regardless, the answer is to simply add a newline character to your title string. The title of a UITableViewRowAction is multiline compat.

```
var buttonTest = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, 
    title: "Line1\nLine2", handler: { (action, indexPath) -> Void in
```

If you want to customize the edit actions beyond the scope of what Apple allows you could always write your own functions that do the same thing or even use a library such as [THIS](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) to accomplish the same thing. This is what we were doing before Apple released the action to the public.

Answer (score 1):

you can use \n to break the string into multiple lines.

```
   NSString *info = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n line 1  \n"
                  "line 2 \n"
                  "line 3\n"];
```

If you want to display the text in a label in multiple lines,you can use

```
    textLabel.numberOfLines = //your number;
```